# PKCS#11. Possibility of performing Ecryption/Decryption in hardware

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hardware, pkcs#11

Cheers. This is a copy of my [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63988/63459) on crypto stack exchange.

I'm dealing with **HSM** via **PKCS#11** C/Python interface. I'm wondering is it possible to do some `C_Encrypt`/`C_Decrypt` in hardware. By saying *"in hardware"* I mean encryption/decryption without exposing the result to the caller space. This is mostly aboud decryption as I want to call `C_Decrypt` and leave the result inside the HSM as arbitrary data to do some other transformations on that data later, saying re-encrypting it on some other key. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PKCS#11 does not provide such methods but certain HSM models allow you to extend their firmware with your own algorithms/mechanisms or even run your own application inside the device so there surely is a way to achieve what you want. Just not with PKCS#11 API.

BTW I've [discussed exactly this scenario](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/pkcs11-comment/201312/msg00011.html) in [pkcs11-comment mailing list](http://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/pkcs11-comment/) of [OASIS PKCS#11 Technical Committee](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=pkcs11) back in 2013. Sadly I didn't receive any feedback `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` but later when I wanted to join technical committee to work on this proposal I received [pricelist with membership dues](https://www.oasis-open.org/join/categories-dues) `:D`.

My mail from 2013:

> I would like to open discussion about secure data re-encryption and the ways it can be handled with PKCS#11 API. Let's say there are some data encrypted with symmetric key `A` and for some reason (i.e. key life-time ended, encryption algorithm is not considered secure anymore etc.) there is a need to re-encrypt data with key `B`. What options does PKCS#11 API provide?
>
> **OPTION #1:** Decrypt data with key `A` and `C_DecryptInit/C_Decrypt/C_DecryptUpdate/C_DecryptFinal` functions and then encrypt data with key `B` and `C_EncryptInit/C_Encrypt/C_DecryptUpdate/C_DecryptFinal` functions.
>
> Advantages:
>
> - uses current well known PKCS#11 API
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - possible security issues - plaintext is unnecessarily exposed to the host memory
> - communication overhead - plaintext needs to be exchanged twice between cryptoki app and cryptoki module
>
> **OPTION #2:** Let's say new PKCS#11 function(s) for data re-encryption would be introduced. It should take ciphertext created with key `A` as an input and provide ciphertext created with key `B` as an output. In other words it should decrypt and then encrypt data in one call. This can be achieved for example by introducing `C_DecryptEncryptUpdate` function with behavior similar to `C_DecryptVerifyUpdate` (it would most likely have similar pipelining issues too).
>
> Advantages:
>
> - Eliminates disadvantages of OPTION #1:
>
>   - decrypted plaintext does not need to be exposed to the host memory because implementation where plaintext never leaves secure device is possible
>   - performance should be increased because 50% less data needs to be exchanged between cryptoki app and cryptoki module/device
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - new method(s) need to be introduced in PKCS#11 API
>
> Personaly I would definitely like to see API for secure date re-encryption introduced. What are your opinions? Does anyone else miss API for secure data re-encryption?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your feedback. I hope they will introduce this king of scenario someday :)

Comment: As it looks like a pretty common case.

Answer (score 3):

No, `PKCS#11` does not support what you need.

Nearest operation to your requirement is `C_UnwrapKey`, which is used for creating a key object inside HSM using decrypting sent data using another key. But I don't think it satisfy your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking about playing around with C_Unwrap. And I'ts the only option I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to re-encrypt the data later under another key you may store it (using `C_UnwrapKey`) as a sensitive generic secret key inside HSM. Then you can later re-encrypt it using `C_WrapKey` with a different wrapping key.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333940/5128464) for example code.

---

There are some PKCS#11 mechanisms that allow basic plaintext key data manipulation -- like concatenation, XOR, range extraction (see section '[Miscellaneous simple key derivation mechanisms](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v2.40/cos01/pkcs11-curr-v2.40-cos01.html#_Toc408227106)' in the PKCS#11 specification), but they are usually disabled by HSM policy because they can be used for key-extraction attacks (see e.g. [here](https://cryptosense.com/blog/the-untold-story-of-pkcs11-hsm-vulnerabilities)).

Technically you can combine them to perform various shifts, swaps, etc.

---

If methods above are not an option in your scenario then using a custom code running inside HSM is possible (as jariq writes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310211/5128464)). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52909293/5128464) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086893/5128464) for some options.