# PKCS11 translate ciphertext under different key

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm, safenet

I'm using PKCS11 network HSM (Safenet). I have data which is encrypted under key #1. I want to use HSM to protect it securely under key #2 without ever exposing data in plaintext outside HSM. Both key #1 and key #2 are available to me as handles from HSM. I know that for wrapped keys it's easy to translate protection to different wrapping key - if you have wrapped key, just unwrap with one key and wrap with another. Is it possible with data?

Comment: I already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310211/3325704

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57265305/5128464) as well...

Comment: Thanks, I also had an idea (workaround) that I could just treat data as a key. Was planning to extend data to AES key size but I see that generic secret is probably a better solution as in link provided. Will try to use that.